# How can I validate an email address in Python without using regular expression?

Tags: python, validation, email

This is what I have. However when I try to pass a valid email such as asm@aol.net it doesn't work. Please help.

```
 email = email.strip().lower()
        if not "@" in email:
            print("Invalid email")
            print()
            return
        elif not (".com" or ".org" or ".edu" or ".gov" or ".net") in email[-4:]:
            print("Invalid email")
            print()
            return
```

Comment: refer to https://github.com/Anu4ruby/python-practice/blob/master/email_validation.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just modify

```
elif not (".com" or ".org" or ".edu" or ".gov" or ".net") in email[-4:]:
```

to

```
elif not email[-4:] in ".com.org.edu.gov.net":
```